Capacitor is placed internally in series of AD7323 ADC input
Why capacitor C2 is placed in series of input in the equivalent input circuit diagram of AD7323 datasheet. Won't it block any DC Signal I want to read. 

Capacitor C2 is part of the input circuit. It is shown in the data sheet as \$C_S\$ in figures 25 and 2: -.

Figure 29 is just a simplified version for the purposes of understanding the input impedance.

Won't it block any DC Signal I want to read.

The input signal charges the capacitor up then, after the acquisition phase, it is discharged.
